# Updating a div on a drop down menu selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a drop down menu that is being populated by a database, and i have a div. The information in the menu is of movies.

I want to be able to choose a movie and display it's information in a div whether it be the name, image or synopsis. 
I believe i have to look along the lines of ajax or json.

Any help or tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Yes, you need to use AJAX and JSON. However, you also need to implement service (PHP, ASP.NET, any other) to process data from SQL database and return it as JSON. There are so many possible solutions. You need to choose one according to the programming language you know and start implementing. Then, we can help you with any met problems.

Comment: I have used php to connect to the database. So i will try with php. Oh and i'm using Laravel. Thank you for your help